# how to use 'overlaps' function for multiple intervals?

Tags: r, overlapping

I try to understand, my dataset whether overlapping (or intersecting) with each other. Let me explain with my example below `df1` and `df2`,  `start`  column means, the interval of the row starts on that point, `stop` means interval end on that point. I try to understand each row has intersected with each other or not, if anyone does not intersect, output will be FALSE. So, there is 'overlaps' ( from the `DescTools` package) function in R, but it doesn't support checking the multiple overlapping regions. You can see the `df1` dataset in which all the rows are intersecting with each other, on the other hand, df2 don't fit this rule, since row 5 is not intersecting with row 2 or row 4, my expected output is TRUE FALSE, for the example; df1's output TRUE, and df2's output is FALSE. Thanks.

```
df1<-data.frame(start=c(100,90,130,110), stop=c(200,140,270,150))

df2<-data.frame(start=c(100,90,130,110, 170), stop=c(200,140,270,150,190))
```

edit1:

```
 library(DescTools)
```

`(1,3) %overlaps% (2,5)`, I try to do this for each row of my dataset, I mean each row compared with other rows with `%overlaps%`.

edit2: My solution is: for df1

```
 x<-combinations(nrow(df1),2)
    
    TF <- NULL
    for (ill in 1:nrow(x)) {TF[ill]<- df[x[ill,1],] %overlaps% df[x[ill,2],]  }
    T<-all(TF)
```

Comment: Perhaps you want something like `all(head(df1$stop, -1) >= tail(df1$start, -1))`?

Comment: thanks @Axeman why did you use -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, that I correctly got your question. But might you look for something like

```
library(DescTools)
 
all(apply(df1, 1, function(x) all(apply(df1, 1, `%overlaps%`, x))))
# [1] TRUE

all(apply(df2, 1, function(x) all(apply(df2, 1, `%overlaps%`, x))))
# [1] FALSE
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You just require that none of the rows start after any of the rows stop,

```
min(df1$stop) >= max(df1$start)
#> [1] TRUE
min(df2$stop) >= max(df2$start)
#> [1] FALSE
```

Comment: thanks @pseudospin but it does not work for `df3<-data.frame(start=c(1,4,5,12), stop=c(3,6,10,15))`

Comment: It gives `FALSE`  as 1->3 doesn't overlap with 4->6. If you think it should be `TRUE` then please add this example to the question and explain why it ought to be TRUE.